# Achieving "one instance per object" as in Entity Framework

Tags: .net, entity-framework, design-patterns

I write a layered .NET 4.0 application. The data layer is implemented using the Entity Framework, and there are repositories that provide the entity instances to the caller, i.e., the business layer. When the entity framework is asked for a certain entity twice (e.g. by key), it will return the same instance, so changes I make to the entity will be reflected in other places the entity is used. It is not really a caching functionality though, since there is no expiration policy, and performance does not seem to be improved much since the entity framework will still query the database, at least in many cases. The point is simply to make sure that there is only one instance (per context) of each entity.

In the business layer, the entities are mapped to business objects which may differ in structure from the entities. Again, like the repositories in the data layer, there are centralized points of access to obtain instances of the business objects. My goal now is, to have the same functionality that the entity framework provides, meaning "always returning the same instance for a certain object", in the business layer. I would like to make sure, that every access to a certain business object anywhere in the application will work on the same instance.

BEGIN EDIT

Context awareness is important! Similarly to the entity framework, the uniqueness of each business object instance should be provided on a per context base, not strictly over the whole application. In the business layer there is also the notion of a context, and each context should have its own instance of each business object. This instance should be reused everywhere the context is used.

Also I am looking for a solution, that needn't be implemented for every single business object class. There are potentially hundreds of them. I would prefer a solution in framework code, that is as transparent as possible to someone implementing a repository. The entity framework itself also doesn't know about specific entity types, still the entity framework is capable of providing this functionality transparent to an entity model developer.

END EDIT

My questions are:

- Is there a name for this "only one instance per object" behavior? What would be the Google search term?
- Are there references, guidelines or best practices, or is there even a design pattern dealing with this issue?
- Are there classes in .NET that are helpful for writing such functionality, or even provide it completely?

Thanks and regards,
Peter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it has a name. It is called [Identity Map](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/identityMap.html) pattern and generally it is just a dictionary of object key / object pairs.

Comment: Great, thanks for the hint! Do you know of a (as far as possible) generic implementation that I can reuse in my business layer, or will I have to write it myself?

Answer (score 0):

Here is sample which can give you a direction. Consider you have class User (with private Id setter):

```
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; private set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Store all users inside repository (I use Dictionary for quick access):

```
public class UserRepository
{
    private static UserRepository _instance = new UserRepository();
    Dictionary<int, User> _users = new Dictionary<int, User>();

    private UserRepository()
    {
    }

    public static UserRepository Instance
    {
        get { return _instance; }
    }

    public IEnumerable<User> FindAll()
    {
        return _users.Values;
    }

    public User FindById(int id)
    {
        return _users[id];
    }

    public void SaveOrUpdate(User user)
    {
        if (user.Id == 0)
        {
            int nextId = _users.Count + 1;
            PropertyInfo id = typeof(User).GetProperty("Id");
            id.SetValue(user, nextId, null);
            _users.Add(user.Id, user);
            return;
        }

        _users[user.Id] = user;
    }
}
```

What is interesting here:

- Repository is singleton. Because you need to have only one collection/dictionary of users to exists
- When you create user inside your program, its Id will be 0. Thus you can define it's new user, or its an existing one
- Reflection is used to set private property value
- Singleton implementation and next Id generation are simple (just for quick example)

Now you can do:

```
UserRepository repository = UserRepository.Instance;
repository.SaveOrUpdate(new User() { Name = "Joe" });
```

And somewhere else you can get same instance of user:

```
var otherRepository = UserRepository.Instance;
User user = otherRepository.FindById(1);
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion! However, your approach has two drawbacks in my scenario, apologies if i didn't make it clear enough: Lack of context awareness, and lack of transparency to the repository developer. I refined my question accordingly. Probably I am asking too much (especially with the second part) and what I imagine cannot be done, but if you have more thoughts on that I'd be happy to read them!

Comment: @Peter what about simple class `Context` with dictionaries for your entities? Btw there is no need to implement repository for every class. You can create generic repository like `Repository<TEntity>` and use it for any parameter: `Repository<User>`.

Comment: In fact I do already have a Context class, and storing my business objects there has crossed my mind. But: I can't simply use your generic approach. My business object repositories require specific logic and they must be written one by one (even though they share a common generic interface). So the crucial question is: How can I make my repositories use the instance cache that is located in the context, with the smallest possible foot print (ideally zero) in each repository?

Comment: @Peter sorry, don't understand what you want to achieve